# Some part of labels and barcode won't print when using non continuous media mark sensing

Tags: ios, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I am having a problem with ZPL. If I am printing using continuous media with the specified length: `^XA^POI^MNV^LL3000` there the printer will be able to print everything. However, when I tried to use `^XA^POI^MNM,10` for the black label sensing, the part from `// Month1Date + Month1Balance` till the barcode will be missing.

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

```
          @"^XA^POI^MNM,10" \

          //@"^XA^POI^MNV^LL3000" \

          @"^LH0,2"

          // Contract Acc no Info
          @"^FO40,199^A0,20,20^FD201004868103^FS" \
          @"^FO340,199^A0,20,20^FDCASH^FS" \
          @"^FO535,199^A0,20,20^FD250^FS" \
          @"^FO675,199^A0,20,20^FD20100034*1^FS" \

          // Address
          @"^FO40,235^A0,20,20^FDTOM TRADING CO^FS" \
          @"^FO660,232^A0,20,20^FD1234567^FS" \

          @"^FO40,255^A0,20,20^FDGR FL^FS" \
          @"^FO660,268^A0,20,20^FD02/03/2016^FS" \

          @"^FO40,275^A0,20,20^FD232 BAKER STREET^FS" \
          @"^FO660,303^A0,20,20^FD18:40:10^FS" \

          @"^FO40,295^A0,20,20^FD93100^FS" \
          @"^FO660,336^A0,20,20^FD1^FS" \
          @"^FO660,369^A0,20,20^FD22/03/2016^FS" \


          // Summary of Charges
          @"^LH0,400" \
          @"^FO40,30^A0,20,20^FDBalance Carried Forward^FS" \
          @"^FO40,57^A0,20,20^FDPayment - Thank You^FS" \
          @"^FO40,84^A0,20,20^FDCD Release^FS" \
          @"^FO40,111^A0,20,20^FDCurrent Month Charges^FS" \


          // left align value
          @"^FO40,32^FB750,1,,R^CF0,20,20" \
          @"^FD10.70^FS" \
          @"^FO40,60^FB750,,,R" \
          @"^FD1054.70^FS" \
          @"^FO40,88^FB750,,,R" \
          @"^FD0.00^FS" \
          @"^FO40,116^FB750,,,R" \
          @"^FD2046.34^FS" \
          @"^FO40,146^FB750,,,R" \
          @"^FD20,869.06^FS" \

.....

          // Reminder
          @"^FO40,540^A0,25,25^FDReminder: THE FOLLOWING OUTSTANDING IS DUE FOR DISCONNECTION^FS" \
          @"^FO40,570^A0,25,25^FDPLEASE PAY IMMEDIATELY. IF PAID, PLEASE IGNORE THIS NOTICE^FS" \
          @"^FO40,600^A0,25,25^FDPREVIOUS OUTSTANDING^FS" \

          // Month1Date + Month1Balance
          @"^FO40,700^A0,20,20^FDMonth1Date^FS" \
          @"^FO340,700^A0,20,20^FDMonth1Balance^FS" \

          // Month2Date + Month2Balance
          @"^FO40,730^A0,20,20^FDMonth2Date^FS" \
          @"^FO340,730^A0,20,20^FDMonth2Balance^FS" \

          // Month3Date + Month3Balance
          @"^FO40,760^A0,20,20^FDMonth3Date^FS" \
          @"^FO340,760^A0,20,20^FDMonth3Balance^FS" \

          // Month4Date + Month4Balance
          @"^FO40,790^A0,20,20^FDMonth4Date^FS" \
          @"^FO340,790^A0,20,20^FDMonth4Balance^FS" \

          // TotalDate + TotalBalance
          @"^FO40,820^A0,20,20^FDTotalDate^FS" \
          @"^FO340,820^A0,20,20^FDTotalBalance^FS" \

          // CSM Name
          @"^LH0,2450" \
          @"^FO40,0^A0,20,20^FDTOM TRADING CO^FS" \
          @"^FO40,40^A0,20,20^FDTAX INV. DATE: 02/03/2016^FS" \

          // Total Amount Due
          @"^FO420,40^A0,20,20^FDTOTAL AMT. DUE: RM^FS" \
          @"^FO40,40^FB700,,,R^CF0,20,20" \
          @"^FD0.00^FS" \

          // Barcode 128
          @"^FO40,80^BC,80,Y,N,N^FD*19809.79*^FS" \
          @"^FO420,80^BC,80,Y,N,N^FD*201004868103*^FS" \
          @"^XZ"
```

Comment: To rule out a communications issue can you try swapping the first half of the print statements with the second half.

Comment: Also, does this print out span multiple black lines? Are you trying to get it to present to the next black line when completing your print job?

Comment: If i swap the two halves, it can print till TotalDate + Total Balance.

Comment: And the black label sensing is working perfectly as I want it.

Answer (score 0):

you should add back your `^LL` command to st an appropriate length, also run a calibration on the web so they system can correctly detect the length of the label stock. 
adding the `^LL` helps the printer to know when to expect the mark, alternatly you can run a `~JC` command to make the printer detect the label length at start (this will use 2 labels every time you change media)